# What is the speed of rate calculation in SD (System Dynamics) in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I was wondering in system dynamics,

If I have a population of 50000 (initial). And if I set a birthday rate of 0.015. Then what will be the birth rate at year 1. Is it going to be ((50,000 *(mult. by) 0.015) + 50,000) or is it going to be ((50,000*(mult. by)0.015) + 50,000)*364.

My model time is set to years.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

neither... the value you get depends on the timestep, your differential equations approximation (Euler or RK4)... and sometimes it depends on how fast your simulation is running because in some cases anylogic doesn't respect the time step.

Every timestep, the value of the population is recalculated... if the timestep is 1 year (don't confuse timestep with what your simulation time units are defined as) then your result if using Euler will probably be ((50,000 (mult. by) 0.015) + 50,000)
but if it's in years, then there's no formula i can write here since the value is recalculated ever day as this if you are using euler (more or less)

```
day1Result=((50,000 (mult. by) 0.015)*1/365 + 50,000) 
day2Result=((day1Result (mult. by) 0.015)*1/365 + day1Result)
```

etc...

Comment: What can i do, to get the timestep to be 200, if i run the model for 200 years?